# Python for .net in windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, .net, python.net

I am trying to run a basic python for .Net application. I have the following installed:

```
    1) Python 33 for 32-bit
    2) pythonnet-py3_beta-py3.3-win32.egg installed with easy_install
```

However, I am getting the following error whenever I work with integers.

For eg: self.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000) and timer.Interval = 60000 are throwing the following error

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'PyNumber_Int' in DLL 'python33'
```

Please find the complete program below:

```
import win32gui
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
from System.Drawing import Icon
from System.Windows.Forms import (Application, ContextMenu,
                                  MenuItem, NotifyIcon, Timer)


class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.initNotifyIcon()
        self.onTick(None, None)
        # timer = Timer()
        # timer.Interval = 60000
        # timer.Tick += self.onTick
        # timer.Start()

    def initNotifyIcon(self):
        self.notifyIcon = NotifyIcon()
        self.notifyIcon.Icon = Icon("app-icon.ico")
        self.notifyIcon.Visible = True
        self.notifyIcon.ContextMenu = self.initContextMenu()

    def onTick(self, sender, event):
        self.notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Hello, I'm IronPython"
        self.notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Who are you?"
        self.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000)

    def initContextMenu(self):
        contextMenu = ContextMenu()
        exitMenuItem = MenuItem("Exit")
        exitMenuItem.Click += self.onExit
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(exitMenuItem)
        return contextMenu

    def onExit(self, sender, event):
        self.notifyIcon.Visible = False
        Application.Exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    Application.Run()
```

Comment: PyObject* PyNumber_Int(PyObject *o)
Return value: New reference.
Returns the o converted to an integer object on success, or NULL on failure. This is the equivalent of the Python expression int(o).

Note This function is defined in the transitional intobject.h header file. It will be removed completely in Python 3.1. Use the PyNumber_Long() function instead.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/number.html

Comment: try newer binaries from https://github.com/renshawbay/pythonnet